# Fetch name based on comma-separated ids

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have two tables, customers and products.

products:

```
productid name
 1        pro1
 2        pro2
 3        pro3
```

customers:

```
id    name   productid
1     cust1  1,2
2     cust2  1,3
3     cust3
```

i want following result in select statement,

```
id   name    productid
 1  cust1    pro1,pro2
 2  cust2    pro1,pro3
 3  cust3
```

i have 300+ records in both tables, i am beginner to back end coding, any help?

Comment: Your  database design is bound to cause a lot of problems. You shouldn't be storing `productid` as a comma separated value column. It will make your queries slower as you will need to use an additional logic to split the values and then join with `product` table. I would suggest you have a look at how to create _Many to Many relationship_ in sql

Comment: It looks like a bad data model. First, you have to split the ids, there were already several questions and answers. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41961621/splitting-a-comma-separated-string-in-oracle-not-working Afterwards you can join the product table and aggregate with the function `Listagg`

Comment: yes i know design is bad but i can't change it, i have to find the solution for it keeping design the same :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Oracle's LISTAGG function with a unique filter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7355095/how-to-use-oracles-listagg-function-with-a-unique-filter)

Comment: it's not duplicate, here i have to fetch the name based on comma separated ids, i dont want to convert it in multiple rows.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely a poor database design but the bad thing is that you have to live with that. Here is a solution which I created using recursive query. I don't see the use of `product` table though since your requirement has nothing to do with `product` table.

```
with 
    --Expanding each row seperated by comma     
    tab(col1,col2,col3) as (                           
                             Select distinct c.id,c.prdname,regexp_substr(c.productid,'[^,]',1,level)
                              from customers c
                              connect by regexp_substr(c.productid,'[^,]',1,level) is not null
                              order by 1), 
     --Appending `Pro` to each value                          
     tab_final as            (  Select col1,col2, case when col3 is not null 
                                                  then 'pro'||col3
                                                  else col3
                                                  end col3
                            from tab )
 --Displaying result as expected                           
SELECT
    col1,
    col2,
    LISTAGG(col3,',') WITHIN GROUP( ORDER BY col1,col2 ) col3
FROM
    tab_final
GROUP BY
    col1,
    col2
```

Demo:

```
--Preparing dataset  
 With                              
     customers(id,prdname,productid) as ( Select 1, 'cust1', '1,2' from dual
                               UNION ALL
                               Select  2,  'cust2','1,3' from dual
                               UNION ALL
                               Select 3,  'cust3','' from dual), 
    --Expanding each row seperated by comma                               
    tab(col1,col2,col3) as (                           
                             Select distinct c.id,c.prdname,regexp_substr(c.productid,'[^,]',1,level)
                              from customers c
                              connect by regexp_substr(c.productid,'[^,]',1,level) is not null
                              order by 1), 
     --Appending `Pro` to each value                          
     tab_final as            (  Select col1,col2, case when col3 is not null 
                                                  then 'pro'||col3
                                                  else col3
                                                  end col3
                            from tab )
 --Displaying result as expected                           
SELECT
    col1,
    col2,
    LISTAGG(col3,',') WITHIN GROUP( ORDER BY col1,col2 ) col3
FROM
    tab_final
GROUP BY
    col1,
    col2
```

PS: While using don't forget to put your actual table columns as in my example it may vary.

Comment: i need to make join with product table because i want to fetch name of the products instead of id, if for cust1  productids are 1,2 then in result it should display row like (1 cust1 pro1,pro2)

Comment: @Learner and on which columns you want to join these 2 tables. Or do you say you want to compare `1` with `Pro1` and get `1` replaced with `Pro1` which is not not possible.

Comment: first i need to split 1,2 and remove comma, then i need to get pro1,pro2 from product table for both id then again i want to append pro1,pro2 with comma and display row like (1 cust1 pro1,pro2)..either by join or by subquery.

Comment: @Learner you can refer this link. it seems this is also urs https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51928702/converting-comma-separated-value-to-multiple-rows/51928950?noredirect=1#comment90834690_51928950

Comment: i have referred that link but that's slight different, i don't want to convert records in multiple rows, if productids are 1,2 then in same row i want to replace them with corresponding name of products, i.e. pro1,pro2.

Comment: @Learner Try to incorporate which I showed there, The result will be  what you need since it already have something with would convert the result as you want. Check for `Listagg`.

Comment: pro1,pro2,pro3 these records are just for example, in my case here i have 500+ rows in both tables...

Comment: @Learner that's fine. My code has nothing to do with number of rows.

Comment: executed your query, but it is showing productids instead of names, i want names of products.

Comment: @Learner Please close this question by accepting the answer if satisfied and ask another one showing what you did and what your expect as result. it would be diffuclt to say what you did and what your got until we see it,